# Use libphonenumber w/ typescript and JSPM

Tags: typescript, libphonenumber, jspm

https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-libphonenumber

I installed that with JSPM. i tried a straight `import 'google-libphonenumber';`

I also tried a d.ts

```
declare module "google-libphonenumber" {
    import libphonenumber = require('google-libphonenumber');
    export var PhoneNumberUtil: typeof libphonenumber;
}

import PhoneNumberUtil = require("google-libphonenumber");
```

I'm just trying to use the format function in my typescript (ES6 style modules) and JSPM. I tried with and without any definitions.

```
import libphonenumber from 'google-libphonenumber'; // module not found.

import 'google-libphonenumber'; // module foun
declare var libphonenumber: any; // needed for TS
const phoneUtil = libphonenumber.PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
```

phoneUtil and libphonenumber is null.

using the code

```
   var phoneNumber = phoneUtil.parse(input, 'US');
   return <string> phoneUtil.format(phoneNumber);
```

Comment: And the problem you encountered was what?

Comment: It worked in typescript before I implemented JSPM and ES6 imports.

Comment: var libphonenumber = require('google-libphonenumber'); TS doesn't like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> var libphonenumber = require('google-libphonenumber'); TS doesn't like it

Use `declare var require:any`.

## Better

```
declare module "google-libphonenumber" {
    var foo:any;
    export = foo;
}
```

in a file `global.d.ts`

Then you can do :

```
import libphonenumber = require('google-libphonenumber');
```